# Movie where people understood every language and met older species of human

Tags: story-identification, movie

Quite few years ago I saw few scenes from a sci-fi movie (or at least I think it was a movie).

I remember people from all around the world waking up on a beach, they were able to understand each other despite speaking different languages, they found some kind of capsules on the beach which contained clothes, I think (the people may have been washed ashore nude), and I think they met like older species of human, neanderthal maybe or something like that.

Comment: @Valorum hit it right on the nose with _Riverworld_. You (k0h3z) should read the books.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be the 2003 version of *[Riverworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverworld_(2003_film))*?

Our hero wakes up on a beach surrounded by naked people, including various neanderthals and historical personages. They fairly rapidly find clothes.

Comment: Ughh that was a bad trailer.  After having read all the books a loooong time ago, this trailer guarantees that I will never watch this particular show.

Comment: @PeterM - You'll be pleased to learn that this was intended to be the pilot of a TV show, and that it got cancelled

Comment: So the trailer *did* guarantee that I will never watch this show!!

Comment: @PeterM If a show doesn't exist, is it really possible to not watch *it* when there is nothing to not watch to begin with?

Comment: @DKNguyen, only if there's no one in the forest. :)

Comment: Thanks for the Riverworld suggestion, im pretty sure it is a movie I watched at some point but doesn't really fit, mainly the "speaking foreign languages" part as I clearly remember they did indeed speak different languages, not just English.